# Arduino AccelStepper Library: Instant speed never reaches set speed

Tags: arduino, serial-port, stepper

I am trying to develop a arduino code which runs a stepper motor with C# program via serial communication. I also use Accelstepper library, especially moveTo() and run() functions. I sent maxSpeed and step values as 3500 and 200.000 from C# and motor start to run immediately.  I sure that it completes all steps, but after a while, I noticed that stepper motor never reaches its max Speed and it stuck at 3200-3300 range. So because of that finish time is increased. If I give steps more than 200.000, the gap between estimated finish time and real finish time is increased exponentially. If I sent speed as 1000, real speed more or less 970. I have to use acceleration function by the reason of needed torque. Then I search the problem and some people said that it occurs because of Accelstepper library which consist run() function and other stuff that I wrote in the loop section. Especially I could not ensure the reason of the problem is Arduino, AccelStepper library or code that I wrote. Can you please help me to solve problem?
NOTE: Arduino Mega 2560 is used.
Arduino code is below:

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define STEP_PIN_C 5 //31
#define DIRECTION_PIN_C 23 //32
#define ENABLE_PIN_C 24 //33
#define SET_ACCELERATION 600.0
AccelStepper stepper(1, STEP_PIN_C, DIRECTION_PIN_C);
unsigned long oldTime=0;
unsigned long now;
float newSpeed;
float maxSpeed = 3500.0;
bool newDataBit, runAllowed = false,addingProg=false,mainProg=false;
char commandChar;
long currentPosition;
long int steps = 0, mainNewStep, addedNewStep,memMainStep;
void checkSerial();
void checkRunning();
void stopMotor();
void runMotor();
void sendInfo();
const unsigned long delayTime = 1000;
unsigned long timer;
int count = 0;
bool running = false;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ENABLE_PIN_C, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ENABLE_PIN_C, HIGH);
  stepper.setCurrentPosition(0);             //initial value
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(0.0);                  //initial value
  stepper.setAcceleration(SET_ACCELERATION); //initial value
}

void loop()
{
  sendInfo();
  checkRunning();
  checkSerial();
}
void checkRunning()
{

  if (runAllowed == true) 
  {
    if (stepper.distanceToGo() == 0)
    {
      stopMotor();
      checkSerial();
    }
    else 
    {
      runMotor();
      checkSerial();
    }
  } 
}
void checkSerial()
{
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    newDataBit = true;
    commandChar = Serial.read();
  }
  if (newDataBit == true)
  {
    ///DoStuff depends on what is received as commandChar via serial port
    mainProgram(stepper.currentPosition(),newSpeed,mainNewStep);
    newDataBit = false;
  }
}


void runMotor(){
  digitalWrite(ENABLE_PIN_C, LOW);
  stepper.run();
  running = true;
}
void stopMotor(){
  stepper.setCurrentPosition(0);
  digitalWrite(ENABLE_PIN_C, HIGH);
  stepper.stop();
  running = false;
  timer = millis() + delayTime;
}

void mainProgram(long currentPositionValue,float maxSpeedValue,long stepValue)
{ 
  mainProg = true;
  if (stepper.distanceToGo() == 0) //YOLUMU TAMAMLADIM
  {
    addingProg = false; 
    steps = stepValue;
    stepper.setCurrentPosition(currentPositionValue);
    //stepper.setSpeed(0);
    stepper.setMaxSpeed(maxSpeedValue);
    stepper.moveTo(steps);
  }
  else
  {
    steps = stepValue + steps;
    stepper.setCurrentPosition(currentPositionValue);
    //stepper.setSpeed(0);
    stepper.setMaxSpeed(newSpeed);
    stepper.moveTo(steps);
  }
}
void sendInfo(){
  now = millis();
  if(now-oldTime > 1000){ //saniyede 1
     Serial.print(stepper.currentPosition());
     Serial.print(" ");
     Serial.print(stepper.isRunning());
     Serial.print(" ");
     Serial.println(stepper.speed());
     oldTime = now;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [AccelStepper documentation](https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/AccelStepper/classAccelStepper.html):

> The fastest motor speed that can be reliably supported is about 4000
> steps per second at a clock frequency of 16 MHz on Arduino such as Uno
> etc.

This is if you do nothing else but running the stepper.
You check your serial interface and send multiple lines every second. Both is quite expensive.